# -Prepare parameter on Access table name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've had some legacy code tossed my way in an MS-Access VBA module. The code uses Access SQL to populate a table. Here's a simplified version:

```
INSERT INTO [Sponsors] (regionname, category, participants) 
    SELECT TOP 9
        [ParticipantsBySponsor -Prepare].regionname,
        [ParticipantsBySponsor -Prepare].category,
        [ParticipantsBySponsor -Prepare].participants
    FROM [ParticipantsBySponsor -Prepare]
```

My question is quite simply: what does `-Prepare` mean?

A couple of other notes:

1. The table/query name `ParticipantsBySponsor` does not exist anywhere in the mdb (at least not that I can find).
2. Of course, the `Sponsors` table being populated *does* already exist, which makes sense.

Does `-Prepare` tell Access to create some type of temporary table, or what?

I have googled high and low for hours. What's between the square brackets is apparently referred to as a 'table expression' in Access, but I cannot find a reference anywhere that describes what happens when you append a hyphenated parameter, modifier, switch, or whatever that is to a table expression. Surely someone out there knows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the `-Prepare` isn't an Access 'feature' or reserved word. The fact that `[PatricipantsBySponsor -Prepare]` is all in square brackets suggests that this whole thing is the name of a table or query.

Comment: You are right. `ParticipantsBySponsor -Prepare` had its Hidden property set so it was not displayed prominently, and 2) it is a Union query, so it was not listed in alphabetical order with the other queries. I had to dig a while, but I eventually found it. I figured it was something embarrassingly simple. Thanks.